# RTC REST API for multiple pages of results

Tags: rest, rtc

I am using the RTC REST API to get data out of Rational Team Concert. I'm getting some results but only 100, and I know there should be more like 1000. Is there a way to get *all* the results, or somehow specify which page of results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't post any example. I found an article (linked below) that answered my question.

Using the following URL as an example: https://rtc.example.com/ccm/rpt/repository/workitem?fields=workitem/workItem[type/id=com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story]/(id|type/id)&size=4&pos=2

'size' is the number of records to return and 'pos' is the zero-indexed position to start at.

So if "&size=6&pos=0" returns A, B, C, D, E, F, then "&size=3&pos=3" returns D, E, F.

By setting 'pos' to a multiple of 'size', you can get pages of results. For example, "&size=100&pos=0" gets you the first 100 records (0-99), "&size=100&pos=100" gets you the next 100 (100-199), and so on.

https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109052/how-to-increase-number-of-records-returned-by-rest-api-call

Comment: Ok, that looks like an url-based solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on the kind of data you want to extract:

- "[How to get 1000+ (all) workitems of project area ?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/45433/how-to-get-1000-all-workitems-of-project-area)" does mention

  ```
  results.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1)
  ```
- "[Paged OSLC query result limited to 100 ?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/140852/paged-oslc-query-result-limited-to-100)" reference to `oslc_cm.pageSize` in "[Consuming Rational Team Concert's OSLC Change Management V2 Services](https://jazz.net/library/article/1001#advanced_concepts)" (advanced concepts).